# Python Numpy, methods of save data and variables

Tags: python, numpy

I was trying to use python package to save some numerical calculation data to a file. I had seen open() in io and os, which mainly dealt with test file.
As I was trying to use scipy and numpy file to run matrix and vectors, I googled some results and it came back a lot.

In matlab, there were mainly two different type of files, one which deal with variable over size 2G, the other was much simple, and two methods to read and save files, one which simply read it, the other search directly though the file without open it.(to save memory)

My question was such that:

1. was there any similar file types and methods to deal with files in python (For vectors and matrix)?
2. Among commands such as numpy.save , numpy.savetxt etc.(for numpy matrix and single value), which one was better and which one was the fast way to use the file (save and read)?
3. I also saw people using numpy.save() with open() to save the file into a txt file format. How to change the format of the file that was saved into, and which type of format was better?

I need to frequently read and write an iterated matrix with each frame about 100MB for 200 frames(at least 2GB matrix in the end).

Comment: Ignore 3).  `save` is numpy specific fast binary format.  `savetxt` is text - csv for 2d arrays.  `scipy.io.savemat` creates matlab compatible files. `h5py` creates HDF5 files.5

Comment: Welcome to SO! Your question is too broad. I suggest your isolate each specific problem, read up on the documentation to aid your question-asking, describe succinctly your problem (preferably with some code demonstration), and explain what you have tried already. Good luck!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`numpy.save`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.save.html) puts your array on disk in binary format.

[`numpy.savetxt`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.savetxt.html) writes in plain text so it is human-readable but takes more space.

My favorite method is using [`numpy.memmap`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.14.0/reference/generated/numpy.memmap.html) to create arrays that are also synced to disk. They can be opened, read, and worked with just like numpy.ndarrays, but updates are flushed to the file.

Comment: if savetxt took more space, does it had more accuracy as well? was there any way to set the accuracy to i.e. 1e-16?

Comment: @JC: No, same accuracy, different representation. All bits used for number representation vs only ~4 bit per byte used.

Comment: `savetxt` writes a formatted string.  You can set the format.  `np.save` writes a byte image of the array's databuffer. It's more like saving a .mat file.