# How to get the list of values of scipy.ndimage gaussian_filter?

Tags: python, numpy, smoothing, scipy.ndimage

I'm trying to get a list of values when I use a `gaussian_filter`.

I read a file with a column and float values. Example:

```
0.8457
0.0
0.505
etc...
```

My script is this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import numpy as np      
from scipy.ndimage.filters import gaussian_filter1d

with open("file.txt") as f:
     m1 = map(float,f)

wt=np.array(m1).astype(np.float64)
wtsmoothed = gaussian_filter1d(wt, sigma=500)
result=np.count_nonzero(wtsmoothed)
print (result)
```

[image]

I want to get the list of values of the line dark red.

Comment: How did you plot the line, if not with the values you're after?

Comment: I did the plot with matplotlib, the line dark red is calculated with  the option wtsmoothed = gaussian_filter1d(wt, sigma=500), this option read the values of a file (wt); but now I want the list of values in a file.

Comment: So then the variable `wtsmoothed` holds the data you're interested in? And you want to save that to a file?

Comment: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Ok, then [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49331558/1354854) for a brief explanation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I got it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is solved with:

```
for i in range(0,len(result)):
    print(result[i])
```